# Ncurses snake waiting

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to do a little Snake game in C and ncurses, and I found that the hardest part for the moment is the waiting. I thought my code would make the main loop to proceed only every second (at least) but it's very irregular, being faster/slower when getch() recors something or not.

```
...
timeout(1000);
...
while(1)
{
    if(!prey)
    {
        prey = TRUE;
        create_prey(s, map);
    }
    clear();
    draw_map(map, s);
    refresh();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    flushinp();
    c = getch();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    if(end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec < 1E9)
    {
        wait.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
        wait.tv_nsec = 1E9 - (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
        nanosleep(&wait, &wait);
    }
    move_snake(s, c);
}
```

I won't detail the game functions because these works well. The only problematic point is the sleep part. I fail to see where I could fail.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: What if you don't press any keys? Are you running in no-delay mode? If `getch` blocks waiting for input, it looks like the screen will stop updating. And I don’t see any check for `c == ERR`, if you use no-delay mode, unless `move_snake` checks for that.

Comment: getch() can't block indefinetely because of timeout. But, yeah, ERR is handled by move_snake().

Comment: How long do those other functions take to run? What if you moved that first `clock_gettime` to between the `if` statement and `move_snake`? Then you would need another `clock_gettime` just before the `while` loop. But that way, you’d include everything but your `if` statement in the time calculation. Also, this is almost surely not the problem, but `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` might be better than `CLOCK_REALTIME` for this.

Comment: I tried to put the first gettime before the if but it didn't do anything.

Comment: You have one too many sources of timing.  Perform a non-blocking read instead of using a read timeout, and do all your delay between ticks via `nanosleep()`.  Also, wrap everything possible in the timed section of the loop, as it is not certain that the execution time of all the other functions (`draw_map()`, `move_snake()`, ...) is negligible.

Comment: I think John might be right. I am not very familiar with ncurses, so I could be wrong here, but it looks like `flushinp` might throw away your input if you hit a key at the wrong time. Is there any way to flush all but the first key in typeahead? That way, maybe it will read your input, but throw away extra keys if smash 20 keys all at once.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried it but forgot to put the drawing section after the getch/move_snake. It works perfectly now. Still puzzled about why it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I put flushinp() just after the getch() and it's perfect. Looks like the same as using qiflush().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version takes a slightly different approach:

1. It simplifies timing calculations by executing game ticks starting on integer clock seconds.  This will give you one update per second pretty reliably, until and unless updates start to take more than one second to compute.
2. It therefore reads the user keystroke via a non-blocking read.  For that reason, it flushes the input buffer *after* getting the input instead of before.

Note that `move_snake()` must be prepared for `c` to be `ERR`, indicating no input, but that's not actually a new constraint.  Note also that `nanosleep()` guarantees only the *minimum* duration the sleep not the exact duration; that will make any implementation based on that function (or on `sleep()`) potentially a little irregular.

```
timeout(0);
wait.tv_sec = 0;

while(1)
{
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    wait.tv_nsec = 1000000000 - start.tv_nsec;
    nanosleep(&wait, &wait);
    if(!prey)
    {
        prey = TRUE;
        create_prey(s, map);
    }
    clear();
    draw_map(map, s);
    refresh();
    c = getch();
    flushinp();
    move_snake(s, c);
}
```

Comment: Interesting way to get by with only one `clock_gettime`. And if you want to be paranoid, you could put the `nanosleep` in a loop in case it’s interrupted by a signal: `while (nanosleep(&wait, &wait) == -1 && errno == EINTR) {}`. And `clock_gettime` could use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, in case `ntpd` or something else decides to mess with the system time.

Comment: Much more elegant, indeed. Just need to put the drawing after the input and it's perfect.

Comment: Too bad you can't increase the speed with this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this code block:

if(end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec < 1E9)
{
    wait.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
    wait.tv_nsec = 1E9 - (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
    nanosleep(&wait, &wait);
}

contains a logic flaw.  
specifically, if the start time was (for example)
5.9 seconds
and the end time was (for example)
7.1 seconds
then the code would think that less than 1 second
has elapsed, 
where (in reality) 1.2 seconds have elapsed
Therefore the code would setup a nanosleep time

what the code should do is check both the elapsed seconds AND
the elapsed nsec, in series, similar to:


// NOTE: following assumes times are unsigned values
#define ONE_SEC (1E9)

if( ((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) == 0)    // not crossed sec boundary
    ||                                    // --or--
    ( ( (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) == 1) // not crossed sec boundary > once
      &&                                  // and
      ( end.tv_nsec < start.tv_nsec )     // end fraction not yet crossed start fraction
    )
  )
{ // then one second not yet elapsed

    wait.tv_sec = 0; // not going to wait over 1 sec

    if( end.tv_sec > start.tv_sec )
    { // then still in same sec boundary
        // calc fraction remainder of this second + fraction time into next sec
        wait.tv_nsec = (ONE_SEC - end.tv_nsec) + start.tv_nsec;
    }

    else
    { // else have crossed sec boundary
         // calc fraction sec time between start-end
        wait.tv_nsec =  start.tv_nsec - end.tv_nsec);
    } // end if

    if( 0 < wait.tv_nsec )
    { // then, need to wait a while
        nanosleep(&wait, NULL);
    } // end if
} // end if
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll sleep better tonight. Using nodelay is more appropriate, though.